# I made button in Python using KivyMD with a help of some one in this website. It works perfectly for him, but for me something is wrong

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

App is made with `Python 3.9.5`, `Kivy 2.0.0rc4` and `KivyMD 0.104.2`. I made `KivyMD` button. With it you can toggle dark/light mode. But it's printing out error and idk why. I mean, it works for this other guy who helped me on this. But it doesn't work for me. I played around with it a  little bit and I've managed to toggle dark/light mode only on this **MainWidget** class. I want to toggle on the entire app. Here's my `Kivy` code:

```
<MainWidget>:

    MDScreen:
        id: screenId
        md_bg_color: 0, 0, 0, 1

    MDIconButton:
        id: light_mode
        icon: "brightness-4"
        user_font_size: "64sp"
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        on_press: app.presser()
```

And here's my `Python` code:

```
class MainWidget(MDFloatLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(MDApp):
    pressed = False

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        self.mainwidget = MainWidget()
        screen = Screen(name='First')
        screen.add_widget(self.mainwidget)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

    def presser(self):
        if self.pressed:
            self.root.ids.light_mode.text_color = 0, 0, 0, 1
            self.root.ids.screenId.md_bg_color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.pressed = not self.pressed
        else:
            self.root.ids.light_mode.text_color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.root.ids.screenId.md_bg_color = 0, 0, 0, 1
            self.pressed = not self.pressed
```

And here's the `error`:

```
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\main.py", line 815, in <module>
     myapp.run()
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 347, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 391, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 248, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1412, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1428, in on_touch_down
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1198, in on_touch_down
     return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py", line 297, in on_touch_down
     ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\behaviors\ripple_behavior.py", line 255, in on_touch_down
     super().on_touch_down(touch)
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button.py", line 969, in on_touch_down
     return super().on_touch_down(touch)
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 705, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1132, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 57, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\my.kv", line 32, in <module>
     on_press: app.presser()
   File "C:\Users\guram\Desktop\WordBondV.2\main.py", line 810, in presser
     self.root.ids.light_mode.text_color = 1, 1, 1, 1
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Comment: Please make sure your code is runnable without any further addition and tweaking.

Comment: Without those "new" dark/light mode codes app works smoothly

Comment: Your `build()` method returns `None` and your `kv` file does not define a root widget, so your posted code won't display any widgets. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend keeping your root widget inside the `kv` code so that you can traverse through available `id` in `ids` dict. In your code, it's unable to find those `id`s.

Here's a working version of your code:

**I've merged both kivy and python codes in one file but you can obv. separate them and later load your kivy file using `Builder.load_file(kivy_file_name)`**

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv="""

ScreenManager:
    Screen:
        name: 'First'
        MainWidget:
            id: my_widget
    
<MainWidget>:

    MDScreen:
        id: screenId
        md_bg_color: 0, 0, 0, 1

    MDIconButton:
        id: light_mode
        icon: "brightness-4"
        user_font_size: "64sp"
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        on_press: app.presser()
"""


class MainWidget(MDFloatLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(MDApp):
    pressed = False

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.screen_manager = Builder.load_string(kv) # ScreenManager()

        #self.mainwidget = MainWidget()
        #screen = Screen(name='First')
        #screen.add_widget(self.mainwidget)
        #self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)
        
        return self.screen_manager

    def presser(self):
        if self.pressed:
            self.root.ids.my_widget.ids.light_mode.text_color = 0, 0, 0, 1
            self.root.ids.my_widget.ids.screenId.md_bg_color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.pressed = not self.pressed
        else:
            self.root.ids.my_widget.ids.light_mode.text_color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.root.ids.my_widget.ids.screenId.md_bg_color = 0, 0, 0, 1
            self.pressed = not self.pressed


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are So Many Errors In Your Code

Don't Worry i solved it for you ;)

**Here is the Corrected code :)**

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp


kv = """
<MainWidget>:
    screenId: screenId
    light_mode: light_mode
    MDFloatLayout:        
        MDScreen:
            id: screenId
            md_bg_color: 0, 0, 0, 1

        MDIconButton:
            id: light_mode
            icon: "brightness-4"
            user_font_size: "64sp"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            on_press: root.presser()
"""
Builder.load_string(kv)

sm = ScreenManager()


class MainWidget(Screen):
    pressed = False
    screenId = ObjectProperty(None)
    light_mode = ObjectProperty(None)

    def presser(self):
        if self.pressed:
            self.light_mode.text_color = 0, 0, 0, 1
            self.screenId.md_bg_color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.pressed = not self.pressed
        else:
            self.light_mode.text_color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.screenId.md_bg_color = 0, 0, 0, 1
            self.pressed = not self.pressed


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"

        sm.add_widget(MainWidget(name="First"))

        return sm


MyApp().run()
```

You don't need to use `root.ids.widgetid` always!

You can define the widget as global widget in your kivy file so that it can be accessed in your python file by using `ObjectProperty`

Also the best practice is to define all the methods which belong to the specific class in your root class itself :)